# Printing some text in a Label, depending on textbox input - PyQT5

Tags: python, textbox, pyqt5

I need help figuring out how to use the value written in a textbox in PyQT5, and use that value to build an IF statement. Any suggestions on how to do it? I have tried to declare the text in the textbox as a variable and use it in the IF statement but I can't seem to figure it out how to do it properly, and every time i run the code, some exit code shows (-1073741819 (0xC0000005) ).

Summing up, can't use pass the value of the textbox to the variable in order to do an IF statement.

I had this code down below:

````
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QTextEdit


def window():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = QMainWindow()
    win.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)
    win.setWindowTitle("Register Program")

    label = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    label.setText("Random Text")
    label.move(169, 15)

    label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(win)
    label2.resize(300, 100)
    label2.setText("1- Register new person\n2- See all regestries\n3- See last regestry\n\nPress ESC to exit\n")
    label2.move(70, 50)

    textbox = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(win)
    textbox.setText("")
    textbox.resize(250, 25)
    textbox.move(70, 250)

    button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(win)
    button1.move(150, 300)
    button1.setText("Submit")
    button1.clicked.connect(clicked)

    button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(win)
    button2.move(150, 335)
    button2.setText("Close")
    button2.clicked.connect(close)

    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


def clicked():
    inpt = int(window().textbox.text)
    if inpt == 1:
        print("Hello")


def close():
    sys.exit()


window()```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you're just looking to get user input, there's a builtin static method you can call for requesting input of a particular type: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qinputdialog.html#getText

If you want to make your own widget however, you need to use the signals and slots to trigger a python method to store the value. This is easiest to do in a class. You can trigger the method whenever the text changes with the `textChanged` signal and do whatever you need to do with it.

(Note, I haven't run this as I don't have PyQt5 currently installed, but it should work)

```py
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Widget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        # type: (QtWidgets.QWidget) -> None
        super(Widget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.line_edit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()

        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        main_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.setLayout(main_layout)

        self.line_edit.textChanged.connect(self.on_text_changed)

    def get_text(self):
        return self.line_edit.text()

    def on_text_changed(self, text):
        print("The text was changed to:", text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    widget = Widget()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Edit: Also, to clarify why you're getting an error, QApplication is a singleton. This means there can only ever be one created. If you try to create a second, you'll get an error. The best way to access the current QApplication is to call `QApplication.instance()`. You also only call `app.exec_()` once, as once the application is running it will continue to run in the background. You should use signal/slots to interact with the UI and trigger the code you want to run.

Comment: oh alright I seem to understand what i did wrong, Instead of trying to pass the whole textbox text to the variable, you used another method (textChanged) and created the function to update the value of the "text" variable! Seems to straight my ideas a bit, thank you for your help!

Comment: But one more thing, how would I now be able to resize the window? As before I had the code below, I could set it up as I wished.

```win = QMainWindow()
 win.setGeometry(200, 200, 400, 400)```

Comment: You can call resize after instantiating the window, ie,
`
win = Widget()
win.resize(200, 400)
`
Always handle resizing/positioning outside of the class so that it's easier to re-use.